# Python Fundamental Counting Principle Possible Permutations

Tags: python, recursion, permutation

If given a list of strings such as `arr = ["abc", "efgh", "ij"]`, I want to know all the combinations starting from the first word to the last using recursion.

so the output will look like this:

```
aei
aej
afi
afj
agi
...
chj
```

all the codes I see are just using the permutation of one string.

I've been thinking that the concept is something like the fundamental counting principle like the one in the picture but I can't really put it into code.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

```py
import itertools
print([''.join(x) for x in itertools.product('abc', 'efgh', 'ij')])
```

Comment: Or `itertools.product(*arr)` as more generic